# Why does inserting a dimension of size 1 into a numpy array invalidate its 'contiguous' flag?

Tags: python, numpy

Consider this array:

```
In [1]: a = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]], dtype=numpy.uint8)

In [2]: a.strides
Out[2]: (2, 1)

In [3]: a.flat[:]
Out[3]: array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=uint8)

In [4]: a.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS']
Out[4]: True

In [5]: numpy.getbuffer(a)[:]
Out[5]: '\x01\x02\x03\x04'
```

So far, so good.  But watch what happens when I create a view of that array, in which I insert a dimension of size 1:

```
In [6]: b = a[:, numpy.newaxis, :] # Insert dimension

In [7]: b.strides
Out[7]: (2, 0, 1)

In [8]: b.flat[:]
Out[8]: array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=uint8)

In [9]: b.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS']
Out[9]: False

In [10]: numpy.getbuffer(b)[:]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/.../<ipython-input-28-0127b71fae43> in <module>()
----> 1 numpy.getbuffer(b)[:]

TypeError: single-segment buffer object expected
```

What gives?  Why does `numpy` think that `b` isn't `C_CONTIGUOUS`?  It definitely is, right?  Or am I missing something?

**Update:** @senderle points out that `numpy.reshape()` works as expected:

```
In [11]: b = numpy.reshape(a, (2,1,2))

In [12]: b.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS']
Out[12]: True
```

That's strange, I would have expected the view to be the same in both cases.

Comment: This is a bit mysterious to me. I notice that it doesn't hold when you use `reshape` to insert the dimension -- at least for me, `a.reshape(2, 2, 1).flags['C_CONTIGUOUS'] == True`.

Comment: @senderle: OP is inserting the new axis in the middle, not on the end.

Comment: @Kevin, you're right, but it's the same wherever you insert the new axis.

Comment: Huh.  Nice observation, @senderle, I didn't think of trying `reshape()`.

Comment: Take a look at `a.__array_interface__`.  All use the same `data` address.  While `newaxis` introduces a `0` into `strides`, `reshape` does not (its strides are either 'none' or (8,8,4)).  I don't pay much attention to the 'contiguous` value.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit mysterious, and I even dug into the source code a bit before I saw [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207077/why-does-inserting-a-dimension-of-size-1-into-a-numpy-array-invalidate-its-cont#comment44782376_28207077)'s comment. His observation that `reshape` and slicing with `newaxis` produce different strides shows what *causes* this behavior -- answering the why question.

But there still remains the question of what *motivates* this behavior -- the Why question. I don't have any solid evidence for this, but my intuition is that `numpy` does everything it can to quickly ensure that slices are views, not copies, and in this case, that demands breaking c contiguity. The issue is that it may be difficult to determine how to add a *correctly strided* dimension to an array with strange strides; it might even be impossible in some cases. But you can always add a dimension with stride `0` to *any* array. So rather than special casing, checking for c contiguity and other possible stride arrangements, `numpy` simply adds a stride `0` dimension.

This laziness makes sense because it's simpler, and (possibly) because it's faster (though a single check for c contiguity wouldn't cost a lot of time). I think the simplicity explanation takes precedence here -- things would get very complicated very quickly in these kinds of situations.

`reshape`, on the other hand, needs to be able to produce arrays of arbitrary shape, so it respects contiguity requirements, and makes copies when it must to do so.